# Buffer Thread Pool in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a way to buffer thread pools in java?

example: 
I have a "BufferedThreadPool" with max size of 3.
Now I execute 5 threads.
The first 3 threads execute. Now the pool is full. Thread 4-5 get buffered
After one thread is executed it will execute thread 4, after the next thread is done it will execute thread 5, etc.

Comment: Do you mean only the pool starts the thread when the current number of active threads is <= 3?

Comment: Aren't You looking for something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int) ?

Comment: You've just described how bounded thread pools with a queue operate, and they are supoorted by the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
// initialization of your threads
Runnable[] runnables = new Runnable[5];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    runnables[i] = new MyRunnable(i);
}

// initialization of thread pool with fixed size 3
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
// passing the threads to the execution threads pool
for (Runnable a: runnables) {
    executor.execute(a);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool` looks like what you are looking for: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-